# Change the favourite to bookmark

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think, the favourite option, which appears below question should be changed to bookmark.

Because, if i like a question, then i will up vote it and when ever i want to check on the same question again. I can do it, by just checking my votes.

Where as sometimes, we might not want to vote on a question(In my case I haven't had that privilege till last few days). But, still if I want to check on a few questions for updates after some time, i was using this star feature(favourite). But, actually those are not my favourites, I am using star feature just to bookmark them, so that i can check the updates later.

So, i am asking or requesting or suggesting to change favourite to bookmark.

Comment: And what would be the benefit of that?

Comment: It would arguably be the more correct choice of words. "Favourite" implies a positive inclination towards the question one is starring. That's not necessarily always the reason for starring, though. (This has probably been suggested before)

Comment: @Pekka웃 agreed, but that was not the intended functionality of this feature. Otherwise, the [Favorite Question badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question) doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: What about this feature request is "unclear" to anyone not going out of their way to be intentionally obtuse?

Comment: More often than not I am just using the stars to bookmark questions that I want to cast *delete* votes on after a grace period, and to follow up if they get better after closing. Not that there's something particularly favourable about that.

Comment: Same happens on Twitter. I 'like' a tweet not because I liked it, but because I bookmarked it for future reference.